# find_in_set within left join in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

How can I use the find_in_set() with laravel query builder. Here is my raw query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON find_in_set(t2.country, t1.fk_country_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DB::raw`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins) like as

```
DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2', function($join){
   $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(table2.country, table1.fk_country_id)",DB::raw(''),DB::raw('')));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use DB:raw as in

```
    DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2', function($join){
        $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(table2.country, table1.fk_country_id)"));
    });
```

===================

Edit : Uchiha answer is the accurate one, since laravel "on" requires 3 arguments: a field, operator,field . i.e `on('table1.id','=','table2.id')`

Answer (score 4):

Using `$join->on(` was generating an incorrect query in my case (Laravel 5.4).

The incorrect SQL generated was like `t1 left join t2 on find_in_set(t2.tag, t1.tags) = where t1.foo..`

Here, `whereRaw` worked for me

```
DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2', function($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("find_in_set(...)");
})
```

Reference: From issue referring Laravel 5.5 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23488)

Answer (score 3):

The above does not work for recent versions of laravel.

Use `DB::raw("find_in_set(...)") ,">", DB::raw("'0'")`

```
DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2', function($join){
        $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(table2.country, table1.fk_country_id)", ">" , DB::raw("'0'")));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work the way the above answers are mentioned.
Use `where` clause instead of on. It worked in my case.

```
DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2', function($join){
    $join->whereRaw("find_in_set(table2.country, table1.fk_country_id)");
});
```