# Laravel 5.2 - Left Join DB::Raw not working?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query where I'm trying to use `DB::Raw()` for the left join but I'm getting error:

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::leftJoin()

This is my query:

```
return $this->model->from('alerts as a')
    ->leftJoin(DB::Raw("locations as l on l.id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.locationId'))"))
    ->leftJoin(DB::Raw("industries as i on find_in_set(i.id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.industries')))"))
    ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
    ->selectRaw("a.id
        , a.name
        , a.criteria
        , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(i.name) SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Industries'
            ->groupBy('a.id')
            ->orderBy('a.created_at', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `leftJoin` function is declared like this:

```
 public function leftJoin($table, $first, $operator = null, $second = null)
```

You want to pass your raw functions in as the second column:

```
return $this->model->from('alerts as a')
                   ->leftJoin('locations AS l', 'l.id', '=', DB::Raw("JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.locationId'))"))
                   ->leftJoin('industries as i', function($join){
                        $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(i.id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria,  '$.industries')))",DB::raw(''),DB::raw(''))); 
                   })

                   ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
                   ->selectRaw("a.id
                             , a.name
                             , a.criteria
                             , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(i.name) SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Industries'")
                   ->groupBy('a.id')
                   ->orderBy('a.created_at', 'desc');
```

The find_in_set suggestion came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410756/find-in-set-within-left-join-in-laravel).

I'm not sure what `'$.locationId'` is, but if it's a variable, you can pass that along as a parameter within an array as the second parameter on the `DB::raw()` function.

Comment: I get error: `Not enough arguments for the on clause`

Comment: Try `->leftJoin('industries as i', DB::raw("find_in_set(i.id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria,  '$.industries')))")` instead. Supposedly the operator and second can be eliminated.

Comment: Now I get: Syntax error near '`` where `recruiter_id` = ? group by `a`.`id` order by `a`.`created_at` desc' at line 5 (SQL: select a.id, a.name, a.criteria, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(i.name) SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Industries'
from `alerts` as `a` left join `locations` as `l` on `l`.`id` = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.locationId')) left join `industries` as `i` on find_in_set(i.id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.industries'))) `` where `user_id` = 1 group by `a`.`id` order by `a`.`created_at` desc)

Comment: seems to be messing up near the `where` clause.

Comment: doing the following works: `->leftJoin('industries as i', DB::raw("find_in_set(i.id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.industries')))"), DB::raw(''),DB::raw(''))`